# How to specify Azure Linux OS Disk Type with Azure CLI Create VM

Tags: azure, operating-system, debian, command-line-interface, disk

I am successfully creating a Linux VMs with the Azure CLI Command...

`vm create --resource-group myResourceGroup --name myVMName --image credativ:Debian:9:latest --size Standard_B1s`

I note that the resulting OS disk is a 30GiB Premium SSD.

Is it possible to stand up the same VM image to non-premium disk or a different size at the point the VM is created, or is this determined by the image I have requested the VM is based upon?

Comment: Any more question? Or if the answer is helpful you can accept it.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to create the Azure VM with the non-premium disk, for example, HDD disk. You can use the CLI command like this:

```
az vm create -g charlesTestVM -n myVM1 --size Standard_B1s --image UbuntuLTS --storage-sku Standard_LRS --os-disk-size-gb 63
```

And the result below:

[image]
[image]

So it means you can use the CLI command [`az vm create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/vm?view=azure-cli-latest#az-vm-create) with the parameter `----storage-sku` to control the disk type and the parameter `--os-disk-size-gb` to control the os disk size.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Below is a list of the `az VM create` options.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/vm

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you.  I had explored the manual (should have made that clear in my first stack overflow post, lesson learnt), but none of the settings appeared to obviously relate to the os disk type.  However, --storage-sku was the one I needed, as highlighted by Charles Xu.  All appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The size name suffix "s" means that the image has SSD disk. You can choose other size like Standard_D1_v2.

Comment: Very interesting.  Is there a Microsoft link where this or any other suffix/name coding definitions are listed?

Comment: I'm afraid that I can't find document or code for you. I've hard that in the online course by Microsoft ( I can't remember it...).